# Specifying the width of a TaskDialog

Tags: winapi, comctl32, taskdialog

I'm using a task dialog via the `TaskDialogIndirect` function.

Everything works as expected except that the width of the dialog is exactly twice of what I specified in the `cxWidth` field of the `TASKDIALOGCONFIG` structure.

Relevant code:

```
  TASKDIALOGCONFIG tdc;
  ZeroMemory(&tdc, sizeof(tdc));
  tdc.cbSize = sizeof(TASKDIALOGCONFIG);
  tdc.hwndParent = hwndParent;
  tdc.hInstance = NULL;
  tdc.pszWindowTitle = L"Title";
  tdc.pszMainInstruction = L"Foo";
  tdc.pszContent = L"Bar";
  tdc.dwFlags = TDF_POSITION_RELATIVE_TO_WINDOW;
  tdc.cxWidth = 150;
  int result;
  HRESULT hr = TaskDialogIndirect(&tdc, &result, NULL, NULL);
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-_taskdialogconfig) says that the `cxWidth` is the width in dialog units.

With the code above the width of the dialog is 300 pixels instead of 150 which means that one horizontal dialog unit is 2 which seems really small.

If I want to specify the width of the task dialog explicitely, how should I proceed? Is suppose I cannot rely on the fact that one horizontal dialog unit is always 2 in this case.

Comment: I suppose that your question is really, "what are dialog units?" I would expect that websearch would tell you the answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know what dialog units are, they depend on the font used in the dialog, which I don't know.

Comment: What are you expecting? It will never be 150 pixels wide if you ask for 150 dialog units. You cannot rely on it being 2 either.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdialogbaseunits, which also contains some example code for properly calculating the values in either direction.

Comment: @Anders I don't expect anything, I want to know what to do in orde3r to fix the width reliably

Comment: @KenWhite [`GetDialogBaseUnits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdialogbaseunits) returns 8 for the x dialog base unit. This is not really helpful as I have a factor of 2 as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: You didn't read far enough down that page, then. There's a calculation for conversion. It's not straight multiplication - it's a MulDiv().

Comment: @KenWhite OK, that works, thanks. Now my only concern is if I can trust the values returned by `GetDialogBaseUnits`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: It's been reliable (and maintained) since the days of Windows 3.x. I'd think you'll be OK.